# Plotly save image original aspect

Tags: python, image, save, plotly, aspect-ratio

When I save an image composed by different subplots (plotly on Python) by using:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.tools as to

py_fig = to.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=4)

... # image generation

py.image.save_as(py_fig, "image.pdf")
```

I noticed that the saved image has more or less equal aspect (width == height), even if the Jupyter notebook displays it correctly (width > height).

This is a problem because, having different subplots, the image get "compressed" on the x-axis.

One workaround I found is to set manually width and height (by using for example the number of subplots to estimate the correct aspect):

```
py_fig.layout.height = 500
py_fig.layout.width = int(4.2 * py_fig.layout.height)
```

However, this is not optimal. Is there an automatic method to do it?